# username_exists() function can't be access without logging in

Tags: php, functions, ajax

I'm using the following function in functions.php to check if a username exists in the DB

```
function check_username() {
   $username = $_POST['user'];
   if ( username_exists( $username ) ) {
       $return['user_exists'] = true; 
   }
   else {
       $return['user_exists'] = false;
   }
   echo json_encode($return);
   die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_username', 'check_username');
```

The problem is that the `username_exists()` function only seems to work if a user is already logged in and checks a username. I tried to check for an existing username without logging in and it just returns `undefined` for me.

I have no idea why this is happening and can't find any documentation about this issue.

My question is, how do I enable a user to check if a user exists without having to log in?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you [**cross post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092290/function-username-exists-cant-be-accessed-without-logging-in-to-wordpress) it on [so]? Do not do this again. Chose your target site and stick with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using Ajax API, and you want to make the ajax callback available for non-logged users, you need to add 2 actions, `"wp_ajax_{$action}"` and `"wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}"`.

Using only the first action, the callback will be called only for logged users, using only the second it will be called only for non-logged visitors.

Try this:

```
function check_username() {
   $uname = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'user', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
   wp_send_json( array(
     'user_exists' => get_user_by( 'login', $uname ) ? 'true' : 'false'
   ) );
}


add_action('wp_ajax_check_username', 'check_username');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_username', 'check_username');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include wp-includes/user.php file when you are using ajax for user related functions.

```
 function check_username() {

   require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-includes/user.php');
   $username = $_POST['user'];
   if ( username_exists( $username ) ) {
       $return['user_exists'] = true; 
   }
   else {
       $return['user_exists'] = false;
   }
   echo json_encode($return);
   die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_username', 'check_username');
```

Comment: When using Ajax API in the right way, manually loading `user.php` is needed only if `SHORTINIT` constant is true, because `admin-ajax.php` [load `wp-load.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L22), that [load `wp-config.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-load.php#L29), that [load `wp-settings.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-config-sample.php#L90) that on its turn [load `user.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php#L121).

Comment: This won't work - `$return` isn't set.